# DIV Position not coming corrently

Tags: jquery, css, html, position

I have the following HTML Code:

```
<div style="width: 960px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <table border=1 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0 width=960>
    <tr>
       <td width=720 height=300>
         <div id="slider1">
            <ul id="slider1Content">
               <li class="slider1Image">
                 <a href=""><img src="theImages/1.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
                 <span class="left"><strong>Title text 1</strong><br />Content text...</span>
               </li>
               <li class="slider1Image">
                 <a href=""><img src="theImages/2.jpg" alt="2" /></a>
                 <span class="left"><strong>Title text 2</strong><br />Content text...Content text...Content text...Content text...Content text...Content text...Content text...Content text...Content text...Content text...Content text...</span>
               </li>
               <li class="slider1Image">
                 <img src="theImages/3.jpg" alt="3" />
                 <span class="left"><strong>Title text 2</strong><br />Content text...</span>
               </li>
               <li class="slider1Image">
                 <img src="theImages/4.jpg" alt="4" />
                 <span class="left"><strong>Title text 2</strong><br />Content text...</span>
              </li>
              <li class="slider1Image">
                 <img src="theImages/5.jpg" alt="5" />
                 <span class="left"><strong>Title text 2</strong><br />Content text...</span>
              </li>
              <div class="clear slider1Image"></div>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width=240>fghfhg</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```css
#slider1 {
    width: 720px; /* important to be same as image width */
    height: 300px; /* important to be same as image height */
    position: relative; /* important */
    overflow: hidden; /* important */
}

#slider1Content {
    width: 720px; /* important to be same as image width or wider */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.slider1Image {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

.slider1Image span {
    position: absolute;
    font: 10px/15px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    width: 694px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity: 0.9;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #000000;
    display: none;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.slider1Image span strong {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.top {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.left {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 125px !important;
    height: 280px;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 90px !important;
    height: 290px;
}
ul { list-style-type: none;}
```

I have two problems:

1. The images coming with indentation and not starting from the beginning of the box.
2. The menu onmouseover goes below the image.

[Here's a picture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/442/errorib.jpg)

How I can fix those errors?

Comment: could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post the link?

Comment: The padding issue is undoubtedly a result of you not removing the `padding` and `margin` from the `UL`. `ul{margin:0;padding:0;}` should fix that issue. The menu going 'behind' instead of 'on top' of the slider is a result of `z-indexing`. Give the `menu item` a `z-index` greater than that of the `image`. If the `image` has no `z-index` then any index `greater than 1` will cause that element to `sit on top of the image`.

Comment: im finding it tough to fiddle because it uses different scripts and css :(
Ohgodwhy, ur answer did the trick!!! Thanks. i know i can count on the people here! always helpful!!! Thanks again.

One question i have is, do you know why everytime i refresh the page i see the whole navigation menu expanded and then quickly disappear?

Comment: What has this question but to do with `jQuery` ?

Comment: Because the menu uses jquery to animate the drop down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set z-index to the drop down menu.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index

Comment: Perhaps you can also help me with this one? One question i have is, do you know why everytime i refresh the page i see the whole navigation menu expanded and then quickly disappear?

Comment: @Jay are you initially hiding the sub-menus using Jquery? If yes, that could be causing the initial showing up and the suddenly hiding.

Comment: i have this code in the HEAD section:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider1').s3Slider({
            timeOut: 6000 
        });
    });